# Differences in execution behavior of Java program

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, apache-poi, xwpf

I wrote a java program, which manipulates Word documents (docx) with Apache POI. It runs fine within Eclipse, and it runs fine as a runnable JAR on my computer (Windows 10).

I copied that JAR to another computer, and it is starting up normally. The GUI behaves like expected.

The problem is the Word document I write out (docx).

I am performing two types of changes. The first one is the addition of new paragraphs or concatenation of content to the runs. If I stay with this, the document gets written into the file system correctly. The second type is the simple replacement of content within the runs (changes of words and some grammatical changes). I would see that part as the "simpler" one, but if I stay with this or if I combine both change types, no document is written out at all. It does look like there is a bug, but there isn't one because it worked fine on my system.

I wrote myself a function to write out an error log (txt) to get information about that issue. This one worked on both systems. But the log didn't get any information, why the document was not written out.

I suppose there are some Windows security settings which interfer with my program or something like that. The computer that does not like to run my program has Win 7 installed on it, and there are some security domain settings, which affect all other computers in the local network.

Does anyone experienced something similar yet? Any suggestions what to check? Suggestions how to find out if an error happened are appreciated as well.

Comment: which type of system were u using, pls kindly state this in the question. also u can try checking the java security profile of the system.

Comment: My own system runs on Windows 10. The other computer runs on a regular Windows 7 installation. Tomorrow I will update Java on the Win7-machine, and afterwards check the security profile. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem got solved by simply updating the Java version. I saw that update icon in the system tray, which didn't open update the update dialog. So I wanted to update the Java-version at least.

When I wanted to de-install the current Java version first, I noticed that the Win7-machine hadn't a Java-update for three years now. It was just installed in 2014. As soon as the recent version was installed, everything worked like expected again.

The strange behavior that some parts of my program worked and some not, confused me. I hoped that the Java update would fix this, but I doubted that. I didn't knew that old versions make programs run unpredictably.